# DiskMarker created before maxElementsInMemory is reached

Tags: java, ehcache

I'm testing things and currently generate and insert 1048576ish entries into the cache.

ehcache is set up to accept 1048579 entries before overflowing to disk and this works.
Except that even before it overflows to disk there's 1048576ish DiskMarkers and they use just a little less of my heap than my actual elements does.

Is there a way I can get ehcache to not create a DiskMarker before it's written to disk?

ehcache.xml follows:

```
<ehcache>
  <diskStore path="/home/deepy/cache"/>
<cache 
    name="first" 
    maxElementsInMemory="1048579"
    eternal="true"
    overflowToDisk="true"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
    diskPersistent="false" />
</ehcache>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained to me [here](https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/EHC-1014) this is expected behaviour.

So if you're looking for a LFU cache, there's no point in picking ehcache unless your entries are much larger than the DiskMarkers.